Call...swap exact token to eth
I send coins from binance to trust wallet and it was successful but it convert directly to smart contract and I don't know what to do coz I don't know much about smart contract. Please help me
0xB06CA52ddEF84DF24E4fE80a65E0EB82c9ff4AF9
Wallet address
